# What's the difference between a property with a private setter and a property with no setter?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

If I want a read-only property, I write it like:

```
public int MyProperty { get { //Code goes here } }
```

However, the Microsoft example (and a few other examples I've seen) are written like:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

Is there any difference between these two, and should I start writing properties like this?

Comment: Yeah, in the second case, the class it belongs to can set its value.

Comment: [`understanding private setters`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847832/understanding-private-setters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in your second sample, you can leave out the implementation for a property. .NET will then automatically create a local variable for the property and implement simple getting and setting.

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

is actually equivalent to

```
private int _myProperty;

public int MyProperty { 
    get { return _myProperty; }
    private set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

Writing

```
public int MyProperty { get; }
```

does not work at all, as automatic properties need to implement a getter *and* a setter, while

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

leaves you with a property that may return any `int`, but can only be changed within the current class.

```
public int MyProperty { get { ... } }
```

creates a read-only property.

Question is: *what do you need?* If you already have a member variable that's used within your class and you only want to return the current value using a property, you're perfectly fine with

```
public int MyProperty { get { return ...; }}
```

However, if you want a read-only property, which you need to set within your code (but not from other classes) without explicitly declaring a member variable, you have to go with the `private set` approach.

Comment: `public int MyProperty { get; }` does not leave you with any kind of property; that's illegal.

Comment: @EricLippert You're right. I changed my answer to account for this.

Comment: `public int MyProperty { get; }` is legal as of C#6

Comment: And what would it return if it can never be set?

Comment: It can only be set in the constructor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 8):

With private setter you can only assign property value inside of instance when property is without setter you can't set its value anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use an explicit member assignment in the property, you'll have to declare a `private set` at least in order to be able to set a value to this property. Otherwise, you'll get a warning at compile-time saying that your property cannot be assigned.

If you use an explicit member, you'll be able to assign a value to this member directly, without needing to add a `private set`:

```
private int member ;

public int MyProperty {
    get { return member; }
}

// ...

member = 2;
int anotherVariable = MyProperty; // anotherVariable == 2
```

Comment: In your example, the use of a private setter to me doesn't actually make sense at all. If I have a private member I can change, why would I have a private setter then? The only reason would be if setting the property did some more than just change the private member.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar You're right. Deleted the private set for clarity. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int MyProperty
{
  get
  {
    // Your own logic, like lazy loading
    return _myProperty ?? (_myProperty = GetMyProperty());
  }
}
```

A property with only a getter is very useful if you need your own logic behind the access of that property, in particular when you need the property to be lazy loaded.

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

A property with a private setter is useful if you need the property not te be changed from the outside, but still maintained from within the class.

In both cases, you can have a backing data field for the actual value, but in the former, you'll have to maintain that yourself, and in the latter, it is maintained for you by the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference when you access the object with reflection.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }
}

// .....
    internal static void Main()
    {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.GetType().GetProperty("Bar").SetValue(foo, "private?", null);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
    }
```