# C# How to Restrict write of a global variable to only the class where it is initialized (so other classes only can read it)?

Tags: c#, .net

As the title states I'm looking for a way how to solve following:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class SetVariable : Form
    {
        public string test = "";

        public SetVariable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = "test"
        }
    }
}
```

and in a second form I want to read it, but also want to restrict the user from making any changes to the variable (by accident or on purpose), as all the variables are only to be set in the SetVariable Form, and then be used across all other forms that are planned.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class GetVariable : Form
    {
        public GetVariable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SetVariable.test == "test")
            { //doSomething;}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I make the variable a public readonly, than I cant write to it in the form where its supposed to be written. Is there another way of initalizing a global variable which is only changable in the form where its created?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
public string test = "";
```

to:

```
public string test { get; private set; }
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847982/34092 .

Comment: thank you for the answer and for the other post describing this provate property further. Have a good day

Answer (score 2):

Make public property private set.

```
public partial class SetVariable : Form
{
  public string Test {get; private set;}

  //Just in case if you want to set value to Test property from other class.
  //If you want Test property readonly to other 
  //class you don't need this method.
  public void SetTest(string test)
  {
    Test = test;
  }
}

public class Main
{
  SetVariable sv = new SetVariable();
  sv.SetTest("Some Value"); //unwanted to scenario. Just in case if you want

  //read Test value
  string testValue = sv.Test; //allowed
  //set Test value
  sv.Test = "Other value"; //not allowed.
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, really helps me with my further programm. Also thank you for the example =) Have a good day.