# Trouble updating WPF with UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

First (full disclosure), I am a relative beginner with C#, so this is probably an obvious oops.  I've reviewed dozens of similar questions and examples here on stackoverflow already and I still can't put my finder on what I am doing wrong.  I started with a VS 2017 WPFapp project. Changed the OnStartup so I could load my window manually.  Created a class with a timer that increments a value and then used  INotifyPropertyChanged to update a TextBox on my MainWindow.

The WPF window loads fine.  The TextBlock starts with a value of 5, so the binding is at least pointing to my class and value.  You will note in the output that the value is updating with the timer event, and the NotifyPropertyChanged is firing but the TextBlock never changes.

My only thought is that the TextBlock is linked to the wrong instance of my UpdateWPF class, but I don't see how that could be.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is my code...

**MainWindow.xaml:** (Really just dropped a textblock and set the binding)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="139,123,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=GetValue,Mode=OneTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (Didn't change this code at all)

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml** (just commented out the StartupUri)

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
            <!--StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"-->
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs** (The meat and potatoes)

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {


            base.OnStartup(e);
            UpdateWPF uWPF = new UpdateWPF();
            MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
            w.DataContext = uWPF;
            w.Show();
        }

        public class UpdateWPF : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                Console.WriteLine("NotifyPropertyChanged Fired.");
            }

            private int value = 5;
            public UpdateWPF()
            {
                Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
                aTimer.Interval = 1000;
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
            private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                value++;
                Console.WriteLine("Timer Event Fired. New Value is " + value.ToString());
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(GetValue));
            }
            public string GetValue => (value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**and the output**

```
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 6 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired. 
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 7 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired. 
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 8 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired. 
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 9 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired. 
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 10 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired. 
Timer Event Fired. New Value is 11 
NotifyPropertyChanged Fired.
```

Comment: its `Mode=OneTime` expected behavior. you don't need to set it. and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is a useless setting for `TextBlock.Text`

Comment: Darn it all.... Mode=OneTime  was supposed to be Mode  = OneWay!

Comment: put that in as an answer and I'll mark in answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASh found my problem, but he posted it as comment so I'll answer this.  Since I've solved a few other things along the way, I post it all here.

**The real issue was in my MainWindow.xaml**

```
Text="{Binding Path=GetValue,Mode=OneTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

should have been

```
Text="{Binding Path=GetValue,Mode=OneWay}"
```

which will later become

```
Text="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=OneWay}"
```

As ASh pointed out, UpdateSourceTrigger was completely pointless in this case.

Loris156 pointed out some other issues.  Some of that suggestion wrong, but I stumbled through the good points and came to this.

**Naming Convention**

I came from java were everything is GetThis or SetThis with *this* being the variable.
MS suggests Value(){ get; set;} with *value* being the variable.  loris156 prefers the *_value*, which I see a lot of people doing.  As it so happens "value" is a very bad example because of the use in the auto property setter.  Nonetheless, I stuck with MS's way, since I'm using their compiler.

So my getter/setter became "Value".

I'll also point out that Lori156 used an int return, but this didn't work for the textbox I was using.

I had been previously unable to get the [CallerMemberName] to correctly work.  This also had to do with my getter/setter.  By excluding the setter, I had broken the auto property functionality.  See [understanding private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847832/understanding-private-setters)

As I mentioned previously, the int getter doesn't work with a text box so I chose to convert the string back to an int in the setter.  It really doesn't matter, since I'll not be using it anyway.
And here is the code changes for App.xaml.cs

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Console.WriteLine("NotifyPropertyChanged Fired.");
        }
```

...

```
public string Value {
            get => value.ToString();
            private set => this.value = Int32.Parse(value);
        }
```

I'm open to further suggestions if anyone has them.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comment above, you have to set your `UpdateSourceTrigger` correctly. I also do not recommend the way you implemented your properties. They should look like this:

```
private int _value;

public int Value
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
    }
}
```

Now you can just say `Value = 0;` instead of raising the `PropertyChanged` event manually.

If you change your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method to this:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgw(propertyName));
            Console.WriteLine("NotifyPropertyChanged Fired.");
}
```

you don't have to pass the property name to `NotifyPropertyChanged`. The runtime will do this automatically, because of the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

Greetings

Loris

**EDIT:**

My property example was just an example for a property, not yours. But you just have to change the type and it will work.

This should work for you:

```
public class UpdateWPF : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Console.WriteLine("NotifyPropertyChanged Fired.");
        }

        private int _value = 5;

        public UpdateWPF()
        {
            Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var i = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            Value = ++i;
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My naming convention needs a little work, no doubt.  If you noticed from but "Get" prefix, I came from Java.

I actually can't see any difference in using UpdateSourceTrigger.  Follow my previous comments, if I change my binding to Mode=OneWay and remove the UpdateSourceTrigger it works just find.  Perhaps that is default for textbox/textblock and someone could clarify.

Comment: Regarding the bit about [CallerMemberName] and not raising the event manually, I cannot get that to work.