# How to change readonly variable's value?

Tags: c#

I have an Account class that contain a readonly variable balance.
Constructor will assign default value as 0.

But i want to update that value when I call `CashIn` method. 
I tried this:

```
class Account
{
    private string name;
    private readonly double balance;

    public Account(string n, double b)
    {
        name = n;
        balance = b;
    }

    public void CashIn(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance+amount;
    }
}
```

But as I know, readonly variable could be assigned through constructor or field.

Is it possible to update balance when i call `CashIn` method?
If yes then Please describe me how?

Comment: If you want to change the value, its not `readonly`

Comment: Actually i got an assignment that tells to keep balance readonly. then how can i do it? how can i change that value?

Comment: I think you should create a readonly property that return the variable value

Comment: Do you ever want to know the balance outside of the class?  Why not use a public property with a private setter?  (i.e `public decimal Balance { get; private set; }`

Comment: @jerinsifat there is a _huge_ difference between `readonly` and a _read only_ property.  I imagine your assignment is to use a property with only a get (i.e a read only property)

Comment: Also you should never use `double` to store monetary values.  This is why `decimal` exists.

Comment: You can only assign a readonly variable through the constructor or when the field is initialized in the declaration.

Comment: Thank you every one for help me to understand. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a *big* difference between the `readonly` modifier and the concept of a "read only" property.

The `readonly` modifier means your field can *only* be set in the constructor.  You will not be able to set that variable to anything else outside of the constructor.  Given the context of your code (a bank account simulator) it seems weird that you would have a balance that never, ever changes.  Which leads me to believe you want a read only property.

A property is the preferred way of storing simple data that has get/set methods.  For a bank account simulator it would be really bad to just have the balance exposed with a public setter right?  So I think in that context it makes more sense to have a property with a public read, and a private set:

```
public decimal Balance { get; private set; }
```

This allows it to be read publicly but its only allowed to be modified inside the class (i.e from a custom method you write like `CashIn()`)

```
public void CashIn(decimal amount)
{
    Balance += amount;
}
```

Please note how I use `decimal` instead of `double`.  Monetary values should always be represented as `decimal`, this is [why it exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

Comment: great answer; covers everything I think

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstood the readonly property. that was read only

Comment: helpful and detailed answer

Comment: That is a big difference. Just ran into this now, was expecting readonly to not allow the value to change (even in the constructor) as if it were a const.

Answer (score 4):

The entire point of `readonly` is that you **cannot** do this, except in the constructor. Since `readonly` is a language level feature, not a strict runtime guarantee: you can *cheat* (via reflection or `unsafe` or various other evils), but it seems to me that the most pragmatic thing is to: *remove the `readonly` modifier*. Since you don't seem to want it to be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a private variable, and a Public Readonly Property that return its value, so you can edit the variable from the same class, but it is read only to other classes.

```
private double balance_;

public double Balance
{
    get
    {
        return balance_;
    }
 }
```

Or you can use private set

```
public double Balance { get; private set; }
```

Check this link for more info: [understanding private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847832/understanding-private-setters)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove a read-only tag for a variable. you can not change a value of read-only variables once it's initialized. 
you can initialize it while creating the object and thereafter it will be treated as a constant for the lifetime of that object.

Answer (score 0):

The readonly value can be changed at constructor level. But it can be initialised at the time of declaration and can also be changed at constructor level