# Facing issue when declaring a private variables in one class and initializing them in another class through a constructor

Tags: c#

The image below shows the `Main()` class and the code I have written in it.
[image]

The following image shows the Car() class and the code I have written in it.
[image]

The error that I face is as follows:
`Car.model` is inaccessible due to its protection level
`Car.color` is inaccessible due to its protection level

In the Car class, the private variables model and color have been given the property by the `set()` and `get()` methods and then passed into the class constructor, the object of this constructor is initialized in the `Main()` but on the line where I print the model and color of the car it gives the above mentioned errors.
I understand that model and color variables are private but I have passed them specifically though the `get()` and `set()` methods so that there values can be changed but that is not the case here.

I was expecting it to work but this error has me scratching my head. Is it because the variables are being initialized through the constructor and specifically when I am creating the object? or is there some other reason to it? How can I rectify it?

From what I have learned so far this way should work, there should be no issue if you are initializing a private variable by get and set methods when creating the object.

Comment: Please don't add you code as pictures. Add it as code-section in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll need to provide a [mre], with code posted as text, **not** images.

Comment: You should not post code as images as thins makes reproducing your code very hard, please read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847832/understanding-private-setters)

Comment: Actually, "Impala" in your code is Chevrolet. not Ford. Other than that, Declare your property as `public string Color { get; }` this will make it `readonly` and you will be able to set it in constructor. Or just `public string Color { get; set; }`

Comment: As I am new to the platform, have little to no knowledge on the do's and don'ts.

Comment: Will consider your recommendations for the next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show the model of a car. For that, you defined a property. But you want to get the value from the field which is private.

So you have just to write `Ford.Model` instead of `Ford.model`. Same for color: `Ford.Color` instead of `Ford.color`.

Important:
Your fields are backing fields. This fields are set in your constructor. And to get the value of them, you need to return them in your properties (I named the private field `_color` because this is a naming convention for private fields):

```
private string _color;

public string Color
{
    get => _color;
    set => _color = value;
}
```

I think you should read some basic information about properties. For example on this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: ^Thank you so much for helping me out, you gave me the correct solution. Will read about properties on the link you provided.